# Implementing form masking js

Tags: javascript, jquery

To implement form masking I followed this example:

http://html.codedthemes.com/gradient-able/default/form-masking.html

Instead of this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date" data-mask="99/99/9999">
```

I want to do this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date" data-mask="99.99.9999">
```

These scripts are involved:

```
<script src="../files/assets/pages/form-masking/inputmask.js"></script> 
<script src="../files/assets/pages/form-masking/jquery.inputmask.js"></script> 
<script src="../files/assets/pages/form-masking/autoNumeric.js"></script> 
<script src="../files/assets/pages/form-masking/form-mask.js"></script>
```

I changed form-mask.js to start like this:

```
'use strict';$(function(){$(".date").inputmask({mask:"99.99.9999"});
```

But that didnt do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

You have the part correct that gets all the fields with date in it.

Then, you have to change the data-mask attribute.  Since its a generic field, we use the jquery function attr for that.

```
$(".date").attr('data-mask','99.99.9999');
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/